# UIMenuController not showing custom UIMenuItem in subclassed UITextView

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitextview, uimenucontroller, uimenuitem

I have a subclassed `UITextView` that I would like to show a custom `UIMenuItem` when a user pressed and holds in the `UITextView`.  For the life of me, I cannot get my custom item to show.  Here is what I am doing in `viewDidLoad`:

```
UIMenuItem *customMenuItem1 = [[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Keywords" action:@selector(insertKeywords)];
[[UIMenuController sharedMenuController] setMenuItems:[NSArray arrayWithObject:customMenuItem1]];
```

Pressing and holding in my subclases `UITextView` I still only see "Select" and "Select All".

**What do I need to do to also show my custom item?**

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I had never implemented the `insertKeywords` method, so the `UIMenuItem` was never shown!